# Why celery not executing parallelly in Django?

Tags: django, celery

I am having a issue with the celery , I will explain with the code

```
def samplefunction(request):
    print("This is a samplefunction")
    a=5,b=6
    myceleryfunction.delay(a,b)
    return Response({msg:" process execution started"}



@celery_app.task(name="sample celery", base=something)
def myceleryfunction(a,b):
    c = a+b
    my_obj = MyModel()
    my_obj.value = c
    my_obj.save()
```

In my case one person calling the celery it will work perfectly

If many peoples passing the request it will process one by one

So imagine that my celery function "myceleryfunction" take 3 Min to complete the background task .

So if 10 request are coming at the same time, last one take 30 Min delay to complete the output

How to solve this issue or any other alternative .

Thank you

Comment: What concurrency setting are you running celery with? And how many celery workers are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are running a single worker with [default settings](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker) for the worker.
This will have the worker running with `worker_pool=prefork` and `worker_concurrency=<nr of CPUs>`

If the machine it runs on only has a single CPU, you won't get any parallel running tasks.

To get parallelisation you can:

1. set `worker_concurrency` to something > 1, this will use multiple processes in the same worker.
2. [start additional workers](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker)
3. use [celery multi](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.bin.multi.html?highlight=multi#module-celery.bin.multi) to start multiple workers
4. when running the worker in a docker container, add replica's of the container

See [Concurrency](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) for more info.